# Number of GC call increasing (golang)

Tags: go, crash, garbage-collection, newrelic, garbage

I have a webservice written in Golang which is running on an ARMv7 server.
After a few hours, the process crashes.
I decided to monitor the processus with NewRelic (with this plugin https://github.com/yvasiyarov/gorelic). I can notice that the memory/CPU use is constant, but the number of garbage collector call and the garbage collector pause never stop to increase.

This service is connected to Redis and MySQL databases, the processus is run with golang 1.6, last stable version.

Tell me if have an idea about the reason why the garbage collector is always called whereas the memory/CPU usage doesn't grow.

Thanks

Comment: The memory use is mostly irrelevant. Run with gctrace=1 to see what the GC is doing.

Comment: I use the same plugin, and the gc pause value is aggregate and only increases as you've observed.  Only useful to observe a dramatic change in rate.

Comment: Have you found the cause?